# Android app with fragments and listviews

Tags: android

I am developing an android app and I have multiple fragments with a listview  in each fragment.

I fill my listviews with data from an api.

I am wondering how can I cache my data so when a user changes the fragment(slide left - right) the data will not be loaded again.

Comment: Please provide some code otherwise there are just some assumptions what you are possibly doing wrong.

Comment: Best way is to store those data in Activity session . Every time user changes fragment check if session already has data if not then call your API else get it from session. You need to be careful that any change is data other side will not reflect here unless restart of App.

Comment: please read these: [ask] & [mcve] & [help/on-topic], to increase your chance of getting answers to your questions!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add your Fragments when you open new fragment rather replace your fragments
something like below:

```
CommittiesActivity abstractFragment = new CommittiesActivity();
                           FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                            ft.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.slide_in_left,
                                    android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
                            **ft.add**(R.id.frame_container, abstractFragment, "CommittiesActivity");
                            ft.addToBackStack(null);
                            ft.commit();
```

Comment: what is the problem in this answer please tell me

Comment: I think people just enjoy give a -1 with no reason. either your answer or mine works fine

Comment: this is just ridiculous.if anyone don't accept answer then atleast say reason for that.

Answer (score -1):

You can use AsyncTask for downloading data while the UI thread is running.

Create an inner class in an Activity extending AsyncTask.

```
 private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> { ... }
```

The class provides methods like `doInBackground(Params... params)`where you can download the data and pass it on to other fragments/Activities after it has been downloaded by using `onPostExecute(Result result)`

The official documentation for the same: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score -2):

I think you can just do that by adding: `android:launchMode="singleTop"` in your `androidmanifest` file for every `activity` tag.

Comment: why people gives -1 without a reason?